# Create dyanamic class to accept dynamic JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api endpoint that receives JSON and serializes it into objects.  Very basic and common stuff.  However, I have a requirement to accept custom user defined fields.  For example, a developer may want to add a custom field for "account #" and pass that along via the API.  I'm stuck how I could define a field on my class if I don't know the name.  I need to support unlimited fields so I cannot simply create a field for custom1, custom2, custom2, etc.

I would think that my JSON could look something like this... where custom_label_xxx is identifies the field label:

```
...  
"custom_fields": {
"custom_label_90": 49,
"custom_label_83": [ 28, 29, 30 ],
"custom_label_89": "2012/05/21"   
},   
...
```

How in the world can I setup a dynamic class to accept this dynamic JSON?

I have Googled forever and cannot find any examples using custom fields.

Comment: Your title needs some work for future questions, don't just use tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saykor's reply is probably correct.  However, I already have tons of business objects to work with and I only wanted the custom fields to be dynamic.  Also, I wanted the Web API Help pages to be generated with sample JSON.  So making the method dynamic would not work well for me.

What I finally did was probably obvious to some.  I created a property on the class that was a dictionary.  When I run the Help Pages it generates sample JSON that looks exactly what I needed.  I have not tested this yet, but I assume it will serialize the JSON into a dictionary.

Here is the property in VB, but it could easily use dynamic in C# as well.

```
    Private _customfields As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    <DataMember(EmitDefaultValue:=False, IsRequired:=False, Order:=11)> _
    Public Property customfields() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Get
            Return Me._customfields
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of String, String))
            Me._customfields = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

This resulted in the following JSON:

```
 "customfields": {
  "sample string 1": "sample string 2",
  "sample string 3": "sample string 4",
  "sample string 5": "sample string 6"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post method can accept dynamic as a param:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(dynamic obj)
```

This will accept every json that you send.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I ended up posting the answer that worked after a lot of testing.  This probably works as well, but it probably would not generate API Help Pages.